# Scrapy spider yields several items but pipeline is called only for first per request

Tags: python, scrapy

Even though I have several items per request, only first one (per request) is making it's way to the pipeline and is actually saved as a Django model instance.

Here is my code, what did I miss?

```
# my_spider.py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = MyDjangoItem()
        headings = x.select('//h2/text()').extract()
        for h in headings:
            item['name'] = h
            yield item

        url = 'http://example.com/next'  # I have custom rules for constructing (not extracting) next url
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

# pipelines.py
class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.name == 'my_spider':
            if item['name']:
                item.save()
        return item
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to move the `MyDjangoItem` instantiation inside the for loop, otherwise it always yields the same object.

```
# my_spider.py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        headings = x.select('//h2/text()').extract()
        for h in headings:
            item = MyDjangoItem()
            item['name'] = h
            yield item

        url = 'http://example.com/next'  # I have custom rules for constructing (not extracting) next url
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```